# CSS display:table-cell loses margin property

Tags: css

I have a css class which works perfectly:

```
.img_holder { width:126px; height:126px; border:1px solid #ccc; overflow:hidden; margin:12px; }
```

However, when I try to center the image in the div by adding display:table-cell and vertical-align properties, the margin stops working and the div goes top left of its parent... Is this a known effect?

new class which margin fails:

```
.img_holder { width:126px; height:126px; border:1px solid #ccc; overflow:hidden; margin:12px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells cannot have margins.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense actually in the way a table is formed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get spacing between the cells you might want to use `border-spacing:20px;`

Comment: to make it work, you have to give "border-spacing" to a parent element which has also the properties "display:table" and "border-collapse:separate"

Comment: @Herr_Schwabullek Thanks for mentioning that. Forgot to add that too.